It keeps changing!
What keeps changing? The answer consists of two words.

      ????????????
      D
       C
        H
         W
          F
           X
            J
             Q
              Y
               R
                P
                 D



 "Caesarcipher" may be written in lieu of the question marks, if the letter beneath each question mark is found by applying a Caesar cipher of varying index (first 1, then 2, etc.) respectively to the question-mark letters. Thus, what keeps changing is, indeed, the Caesar cipher.


Yup that's it, well done!
